# What is the proper way to create hierarchical structure of portal in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

Whats the best approach to create a hierarchy of portal?

lets make "Computer" as an example.
"Computer" would be the Parent of all portals. Computer will be having a sub-portal/child like "Laptop", "Desktop" and "Printers". Then for each child it would also have another sub-portal/child like "HP Laptop", "Lenovo Laptop" or "HP Desktop" etc.

[image]

For every portal it would have different look and feel. Some of the portal will share portlet and content from each other. example "USB Products" will borrow portlets from "IBM Desktop" or "Brothers Printers" will borrow content from "HP Laptop".

Any user of the "Portal" can access all those portal without signing-up again. That means a user from "HP Printers" can access "HP Laptops". Each Portal is an individual of each own, it will have its own domain But at the backend they share portlets and other resources.

I hope this make sense.

Whats the best way to do it?

Is it creating a "Portal Instance"?

or it should be in "Organization"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Liferay Portal here is how the data is scoped:

```
Portal Instance
  Community
    Content data (wiki, message boards, etc)

  Users

  Organizations
    Content data (wiki, message boards, etc)

  Roles

  etc.
```

And then there is of course the Global scope that will allow you to share content data if it makes sense to.

For creating a system like the Yahoo! portal, I would use a single Portal Instance (so that you can reuse users) and have a different Community for each service (eg Answers, Finance) as they don't share content data.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options here:

- Create a **hierarchy of organizations**. Each organization will have its own set of pages. Advantage is that you can assign different domain names to each organization. Downside is that it is more difficult to share content between organizations.
- Create **one big organization or community** and use the page hierarchy to direct your users to the proper parts of the site. Advantage is the ease of configuration and the single point of administration. Downside is that you can't have different domain names for each "subsite".

From my experience, most of the time it is easier to actually make everything in one group (community or organization). You lose the advantage to have separate domain names for each subsite, but the same effect can be reached by using proper, human-readable URLs.

If you still want to use multiple organizations, be aware that your content is not easily shared unless you use the Global Scope. But if you do that, there is really no point of using diffent groups at all, apart from the domain name issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- Create new tab on the tab bar by clicking it and selecting new.
- Go to Manage Pages and there you can add Childs and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't referring to page hierarchy. A similar thing i want to achieve is Yahoo. Yahoo is a parent portal and "Yahoo Answer", "Yahoo Mail", "Yahoo Finance"... would be its child. Those child would can also have sub child. Now each of those child are independent portal of its own, they can have unique domain name and still preserve its user database. Each user can still login to each portal with same login info.

Answer (score 0):

Some new ideas:
Organizations approach keeps the pages inside the same program when the instance thing runs several instances on the same server that are separate of each other by URL. 
Building hierarchies and having different layouts is as easy or complicated on both but common user rights may be easier on organization approach. You don't have to think about the passing of the session to another instance.